# Sorting array of array php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, associative

I'm working on a little project based on codeigniter, I'm not a php developer and this is my problem:

```
       foreach ($checkeds['id_iscritti'] as $checked){

        $iscritto = $this->pellegrinaggio_iscritti_m->get_iscritto($checked);

        $utente = $this->utenti_m->get_utente($iscritto[0]->id_utente);

        echo ("utente:   <pre> ");var_dump($utente);echo ("   </pre> \n\n");

    }
```

this is the code, it basically generate an associative array

and this is what i obtain from the var_dump:

```
array(1) { [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#38 (27) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "254"
    ["nome"]=>
    string(13) "Padre EDUARDO"
    ["cognome"]=>
    string(9) "ANATRELLA"    
  }
}

utente:
 array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#37 (27) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "338"
    ["nome"]=>
    string(4) "ELSA"
    ["cognome"]=>
    string(5) "PAONE"      
  }
}
```

How can i sort the array $utenti by the index "nome"?
I've spent some hours, to understand how this kind of array works, without any results, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPs usort() function allows you to sort array using a custom function.

Assuming your array of objects is stored in `$utente`, the following will compare each object against each other object using the anonymous comparison function.

In the following code the `$utente` array will be sorted ascending by `nome` value.

```
usort($utente, function($a, $b){
   if ($a->nome > $b->nome) {
      return 1;
   }elseif($a->nome < $b->nome){
      return -1;
   }else{
     return 0;
   }
});
```

More details can be found at http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 1):

This is the function you want:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Your code should look something like this:

```
$sorted = array_multisort($utente, 'nome', SORT_ASC);
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but i'm sure `array_multisort()` only sorts arrays of arrays, not arrays of objects?

Comment: It seems you're right, I missed that. The other answer (yours) is correct.